# A probably wrong proof of the Riemann Hypothesis, but where is the mistake?

Tags: proof-verification, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

There has been a paper doing rounds on Facebook for the past several days, claiming a proof of the Riemann hypothesis. I feel sure that the argument is flawed, but can't see where exactly. It goes as follows:

Let $\pi(x)$ be the number of primes not exceeding $x$ and $Li(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t}$. Consider the prime zeta function

$$\sum_{p} p^{-s} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$$ for $\Re(s)=\sigma>1$, where $\mu$ and $\zeta$ denote the Mobius and Riemann zeta functions, respectively.

Applying partial summation to the left-hand side sum over primes $p$ together with the identity $\int_{1}^{\infty} s Li(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x=-\log(s-1)$ for $\sigma>1$ yields

$$s\int_{1}^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x-\log((s-1)\zeta(s))=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}\log \zeta(ms)$$ for $\sigma>1$, where $\Theta\leq 1$ denotes the supremum of the real parts of the zeros of $\zeta$.
The integral on the left-hand side shall be referred to as $F (s)$ forthwith.

We know that $|π(x) − Li(x)| \ll x ^{\Theta} \log x$ and $\Theta$ is the abscissa of convergence of $F (s)$
(Theorem 1.3 of Montgomery-Vaughan). Thus the domain of the above equation extends by analytic continuation to the half-plane
$H = \lbrace s : σ > Θ \rbrace.$

Notice that the right-hand side of the above equation converges whenever $σ > 1/2$ since
$|μ(m) \log ζ(ms)| \ll 2^{ −mσ}$ for all $m ≥ 2$ and $σ > 1/2.$ Thus we arrive at $Θ ≤ 1/2$, which proves the Riemann hypothesis ?

Comment: Hint: if the RH would be solvable in 2 paragraphs it would already have been done so.

Comment: I’m not an expert in analytic number theory, but $F(s)$ can have a meromorphic continuation well beyond its convergence abscissa ($\zeta$ is an example), invalidating the very last deduction.

Comment: @Klangen: while it is a sound rule of thumb, it does little to actually find the fault in the “proof”.

Comment: @Klangen, that was also my heuristic argument against the proof. But i would be much more satisfied if i could find a mathematical reason against it.

Comment: @Mindlack, yes $F(s)$ can be meromorphically continued to $\sigma>0$. But i think $\log ((s-1)\zeta(s))$ can only be meromorphically continued to $\sigma>\Theta$, which seems necessary for the last equation and the rest of the argument.

Comment: @user697626: right, I had forgotten about the $\zeta$ term. Two questions then: are you sure $F$ can be meromorphically extended to $\sigma >1/2$ regardless of the Riemann hypothesis, and where does the integral equality with $Li$ come from? Which $Li$ is it (the exact integration bounds in the definition are nonsensical)?

Comment: @Mindlack, i'm not an expert, but it is known that $\sum_{p}p^{-s}$ has a meromorphic continuation to $\sigma>0$ except at the zeros of $\zeta$, hence $F$ must also have such. On the integral equality with $Li$, the author claimed in his Facebook post that it can be found in Montgomery-Vaughan (p.471). The $Li(x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{\log t}$, was defined as its Cauchy principal value around the lower bound of integration $t=1$.

Comment: I am not 100 percent sure, but basically, we have $F(s) - \log \zeta_1(s)=G(s)$ where $G$ analytic on $\sigma > 1/2$, the LHS meromorphic on $\sigma > \Theta$, and $F(s)$ meromorphic on $\sigma > 0$ except the zeros of $\zeta$... so this only shows that $L(s)=\log{(s-1)\zeta(s)}$ has a meromorphic continuation on $\sigma > 1/2$ except on the zeroes of $\zeta$. This means that at singular points, $L(s)$ can have any behavior it wants, so you can’t infer anything more on $\zeta$, can you?

Comment: @Mindlack, the pith of the claimer's argument seems to be that, since the domain of the equation extends by analytic continuation to $\sigma>\Theta$ and the RHS converges whenever $\sigma>1/2$, we then have $\Theta \leq 1/2$ ?

Comment: Such an equation simply means that the LHS can be meromorphically continued, not that convergence is achieved on said meromorphic continuation.

Comment: Maybe someone could let us know where to find this (attempted) proof of the Riemann Hypothesis and/or the author's name?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, i saw it in a certain math group called ''Terrence Tao Fan club'' on Facebook. I was also told that the paper appears in other groups on FB.

Comment: @Mindlack, it seems to me that the author's reasoning is: the domain of the equation is exclusively the half-plane $H=\lbrace s: \sigma>\Theta \rbrace$. Since the right-hand side converges *whenever* $\sigma>1/2$, it follows that $\sigma=1/2 + \epsilon$ is part of this domain for any $\epsilon>0$, leading to $\Theta\leq 1/2$. For example, one has $H(s)=s\int_{1}^{\infty}Li(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$ for $\sigma>3$, say.

Comment: (Continuation of the previous comment) Suppose we didn't know that this equation is valid whenever $\sigma>1$ and let $\theta$ be the abscissa of convergence of $\int_{1}^{\infty}Li(x)x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$. Since $\log(s-1)$ is analytic whenever $\sigma>1$, it follows that the domain of $H(s)$ extends by analytic continuation to the half-plane $G=\lbrace s: \sigma>1 \rbrace$ which yields $\theta \leq 1$.

Comment: Yes, but it is not proved that the domain of the LHS is exclusively $\{\sigma > \Theta\}$. Actually, we just showed there was a meromorphic continuation of the LHS, but this did not imply further convergence of the terms, or at interesting points at any rate (zeroes of $\zeta$).

Comment: The fact that the domain of the LHS is exclusively $\lbrace \sigma>\Theta \rbrace$ seems to follow from the fact that $\Theta$ is the abscissa of convergence of $F(s)$ and $\zeta(s)\neq 0$ if and only if $\sigma>\Theta$.

Comment: So, let's have the function $f(s)=\frac{1}{s^2(s-x)}$ where $x>0$ but not explicitly known and let $g(s)=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2(s-x)}$. Let $g(s)-f(s)=h(s)$ We know that the LHS above converges for $\Re s > x$ (since that's where $f,g$ avoid poles) and we know that the RHS converges for $\Re s >0$, hence since LHS=RHS, we can conclude that $x=0$ !!! That is your (and the post) argument in a nutshell and it's wrong

Comment: Point of correction, its not ''my argument''. And you seem to ignore the crucial point that one is considering the abscissa of convergence of the terms on the LHS. In your ''counter-example'', what is the analogue of Θ , if at all it exists ?

Comment: The author appears to be https://mathoverflow.net/users/97990/tatenda-isaaac-kubalalika who made one brief appearance on MathOverflow a few years back. @reuns was not impressed. Kubalalika appears to have posted an elementary proof of Fermat's Last Theorem, http://vixra.org/abs/1701.0318 Here is the RH "proof", on vixra: http://vixra.org/abs/1811.0371

Comment: I have rolled back this post to the previous edit. Please note that if someone intends to claim a post should be removed due to intellectual property reasons, the appropriate course of action to take is to use the `Contact` link at the bottom of any page and to give a takedown request. This is not something that individual (volunteer) site moderators handle, and certainly not informally.

Answer (score 15):

While @reuns clearly showed the fallacy, the following is a simple explanation without getting bogged down in details that one can spin around in circles as we saw so often in this purported "proofs" here or on MO

The "proof" has the logical structure: RH is equivalent to the analyticity of $A(s), \Re s > \frac{1}{2}$ which is equivalent to the analyticity of $B(s), \Re s > \frac{1}{2}$.

We show that $A(s)-B(s)$ extends analyticaly to $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$ hence we conclude RH (hence) that both $A(s), B(s)$ extend analyticaly to $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$.

I think that this shows clearly the fallacy of the proof since for example $f(s)-f(s)$, where $f$ is any analytic functions on some domain, extends analytically to the whole plane...

Comment: That's not the structure of the ''proof'' at all. At no point does the author claim that $s\int_{1}^{\infty}(\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x$ and $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$ are analytic because the RHS is analytic.

Comment: the third line from the end the "proof" says: "Notice that the right-hand side of the above equation converges whenever $\sigma > \frac{1}{2}$"...

Comment: yes, but it didn't proceed to claim that the *individual* terms on the LHS are themselves analytic for $\sigma>1/2$.

Comment: no, it claimed RH which is EQUIVALENT to each term on LHS analytic, so while it did not make the explicit claim, it made it implicitly by claiming RH

Comment: the other sleight of hand is using $\Theta$ as the true fact that both $A(s), B(s)$ extend precisely to $\sigma =\Theta$, DOESN'T PRECLUDE $A(s)-B(s)$ extending way beyond as I have shown through a trivial example, so from the fact that RHS, hence $A(s)-B(s)$ extends to $\frac{1}{2}$ it doesn't follow in any way or shape that $\Theta$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I don't see where the RH is being claimed. The argument is basing on the fact that the domain of the LHS is exclusively $\lbrace s: \sigma>\Theta \rbrace$ which follows from the definition of $\Theta$. The claimer then combined this with the fact that the RHS converges whenever $\sigma>1/2$.

Comment: what is the last line then: "Thus we arrive at $\Theta$ ≤1/2" (this as noted is equivalent to RHS) so this is a passive-aggressive way to claim RH while questioning the claim... So yes the above "proof" claims RH, so sorry but your comment is disingenuous

Comment: "The argument is basing on the fact that the domain of the LHS is exclusively $\sigma > \Theta$ - that is false as I have shown with a counterxample as you can easily have the difference of two functions converge way beyond the domain of convergence of each (which in this case is indeed $\Theta$);

Comment: yes, just as in comment under the post take $f(s)=\frac{1}{s^2(s-a)}$, $a>0$ not explicitly known and $g(s)=\frac{1}{s}+\frac{1}{s^2(s-a)}$, $g(s)-f(s)=h(s)$. LHS converges for $\Re s >a$ (since $f,g$ have poles at $a>0$, while RHS converges for $\Re s >0$, so we conclude by your reasoning, $a=0$!!!

Comment: $\Theta = a$ since LHS converges for $\Re s >a$ and each term on LHS has poles on $\Re s =a$; as noted, we can do logarithmic singularities if that's the next objection; can do Dirichlet series too if that is the next next objection...

Comment: Not that i'm confident of the claimer's argument myself, but it's clear that you're just desperate to discredit it with little or no valid justification. This makes it un-worthwhile for me to continue in this discussion. Suit yourself mate, bye.

Comment: as I said in other threads like this, good luck with the claim!

Comment: see the edit. The issue that you raised appears to have been addressed (circumvented).

Comment: the proof is still wrong because we still have the fact that if two functions have a given domain convergence, their difference may have a much higher domain of convergence

Comment: Conrad, i don't see how that is an objection to the recent argument. You should know to know that the recent argument has already impressed a few Ivy professors already (although they are not analytic number theorists). I'm eagerly waiting for any counter-example/counter-argument that you will cook up this time around.

Comment: very good for you - the argument is still wrong, but I am waiting for it to be published and then we can talk further

Comment: that which doesn't conform to your wishes isn't necessarily wrong.

Comment: I've kept track of your rushed objections. Firstly, you objected that  '' if two functions have a given convergence domain, their difference may have a much higher domain of convergence...'' and I showed that objection to be wrong. 2.) Then you quickly sought another objection: this time you said that $F(s)$ doesn't have an abscissa of convergence $\Theta$, and I showed that you were wrong as well... then you desperately looked for another counter-example about $\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$, which was wrong as well. You're clearly sadistic and obsessed with seeing the argument being wrong. Shame !

Answer (score 11):

If we care of $Li(x)=1_{x>2}\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$ it is because its Mellin transform is $$L(s)= \int_2^\infty Li(x)x^{-s-1}dx= \int_2^\infty \frac1{\log x}\frac{x^{-s}}{s}dx=\frac1s (2Li(2)-\int_2^s\int_2^\infty x^{-z}dxdz)$$$$=\frac1s(2Li(2)-\int_2^s \frac{2^{1-z}}{z-1}dz)=\frac{F(s)}{s}-\frac{\log (s-1)}{s}$$

where $F(s)=2Li(2)-\int_2^s \frac{2^{1-z}-1}{z-1}dz$ is entire. With $P(s)=\sum_p p^{-s}$

$$\frac{P(s)}{s}+\frac{\log(s-1)}{s}=\int_0^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x+\frac{F(s)}{s} $$

and

$$s\int_0^{\infty} (\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1}  \mathrm{d}x-\log\zeta(s)-\log(s-1)=-F(s) -\sum_{p^k,k\ge 2}\frac{p^{-sk}}{k}$$

> where $\color{red}{the\ RHS}$ converges and is analytic for $\Re(s) >1/2$, it doesn't mean the integral on the LHS converges for $\Re(s)>1/2$ which is what the RH is about.

So this doesn't tell anything of the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: I was wondering when reuns would show up :)

Comment: Where is the flaw now ?

Comment: Thanks reuns. But how does this answer the asked question ? Can you explain further ?

Comment: @Reuns it seems what you wrote is not very different from what the claimer wrote. The only addition you made is your last statement ''this doesn't tell anything of the RH''. What we want to understand is *why* does it have nothing to do with the RH ?

Comment: I'm no expert, but i wouldn't take lightly the fact that $\Big(s\int_{1}^{\infty}(\pi(x)-Li(x))x^{-s-1} \mathrm{d}x - \log((s-1)\zeta(s))\Big)$ is analytic for $\sigma>1/2$. Though this on its own doesn't prove the RH, note that the RH is equivalent to the analyticity of $\log \zeta(s)$ for $\sigma>1/2$...

Comment: @user697626 Please take a look at the red part, does it answer to what you meant, or is it something else ?

Comment: @Reuns, the ''punch-line'' of the claimer's argument seems to be that,''since the domain of the equation extends by analytic continuation to $\sigma>\Theta$ and the RHS converges whenever $\sigma>1/2$, we then have $\Theta \leq 1/2$...''

Comment: @user697626 The Riemann hypothesis is actually equivalent to the analycity you mentioned ?

Comment: The RH is equivalent to the analyticity of $\log \zeta(s)+\log (s-1),P(s)+\log (s-1)$ for $\Re(s)>1/2$ and from the Tauberian theorems to the convergence of their corresponding Mellin transforms integrals

Comment: @Peter, yes the RH is equivlent to the analyticity of   $\log((s-1)\zeta(s))$  for $\sigma>1/2$...not the analyticity of $\log \zeta(s)$ that i initially mentioned since $\zeta(s)$ has a pole at $s=1$.

Comment: @reuns, see the edit. The issue that you raised appears to have been addressed (circumvented).

Comment: Since $P(s)-\log\zeta(s)$ has no logarithmic singularities for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$, I don't see how proving the equivalence of any two representations for $P(s)-\log\zeta(s)$ for $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ has anything to do with the Riemann hypothesis. For $P(s)-\log\zeta(s)$, all of the logarithmic singularities caused by the non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ occur at $\Re(s)<\frac{1}{2}$. Am I wrong?